# Prototype Javascript Error (only in IE) 'Object doesn't support this property or method'

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, prototypejs

One of our devs through together a banner rotater, and while it works fine in NOT IE, IE is throwing an error at line 30 (marked below with "***** ERROR ON NEXT LINE"). Can I not sort $$('.banner')?

The error is:
**'Object doesn't support this property or method'**

**Using Prototype 1.6.0.3**

```
function changeBanners() {

  // banners are now sorted by their z index so that
  // the ones most in front should be most on top in the DOM
  // ***** ERROR ON NEXT LINE

  banners = $$('.banner').sort(function (a,b){
    _a = parseInt(a.style.zIndex);
    _b = parseInt(b.style.zIndex);
    return _a < _b ? 1 : _a > _b ? -1 : 0;
  });

  // increment z index on all of the banners
  Element.extend(banners);

  banners.each( function (banner){

    Element.extend(banner);
    banner.style.zIndex = parseInt(banner.style.zIndex) + 1;
  });

  // move the first banner to be the last
  first_banner = banners.shift();
  banners.push(first_banner);

  // set it invisible
  Effect.toggle( first_banner.id , 'appear' , {
    duration: 2.0,
    afterFinish: function(){
      first_banner.style.zIndex = 0;  // update its z index so that it is at the end in the DOM also
      first_banner.show();            // make it reappear so that when the one in front of it disappears, it will show through
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Try to pass an empty function to the `sort` method and check for errors.

Comment: An empty function threw "Number Expected". Throwing a > b as the sort function returned the "Object doesn't support this property or method" error.

Comment: Crescent - same error - IE's horrible debugger is whining at the code below at "finally {"

  onTimerEvent: function() {
    if (!this.currentlyExecuting) {
      try {
        this.currentlyExecuting = true;
        this.execute();
      } finally {
        this.currentlyExecuting = false;
      }
    }
  }
});

Comment: @Jarrett: see http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/11/bug-184-catch-to-try-catch-finally-in.html

Comment: @Crescent Fresh - That definitely sounds like my problem, but my above fix using element.extend still yields the same results. Do you see anything specific I might have missed? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sigh*

After all of that, it's my lack of remembering to declare variables in JS

Changed:

```
banners = $$('.banner').sort(function (a,b){
    _a = parseInt(a.style.zIndex);
    _b = parseInt(b.style.zIndex);
    return _a < _b ? 1 : _a > _b ? -1 : 0;
  });
```

to:

```
var banners = $$('.banner').sort(function (a,b){
    _a = parseInt(a.style.zIndex);
    _b = parseInt(b.style.zIndex);
    return _a < _b ? 1 : _a > _b ? -1 : 0;
  });
```

Works fine.